# Array returns string of "Undefined" GAS

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have some code that copies data from one spreadsheet to another. I created an array in the source spreadsheet. When I run the script the array returns the string value of "Undefined". This is a continuation of [this script.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005181/move-data-from-cells-in-worksheet-to-another-gas/18007676?noredirect=1#18007676) Here is the line in question:

```
var dataValues = dataSheet.getRange("A"+(dataLastRow)+":G"+(dataLastRow)).getValues();
```

When I try to extract the string value from that array with this:

```
var firstName = destSheet.getRange(destLastRow, 4);
  firstName.setValue(dataValues[1]);
```

It copies "undefined" in the destination spreadsheet. It seems that everything else is working, for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=es#getValues%28%29) ​​returns a JavaScript 2d array, try something like:

```
firstName.setValue(dataValues​​[0][0]);
```