# sheet.getRange is not found with my set of parameter

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I try to run a script on a google spreadsheet to fasten a bunch of repetitive actions.
According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange%28Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer%29), I can access a range of data with a four numerical arguments `getRange` overload.
My problem, is that when I run the script google says me *getRange(Number,Number,Number,Number) is not found* and stops the script.

Here is the code :

```
function addMonth(){
  var month = ["Janvier","Février","Mars","Avril","Mai","Juin",
               "Juillet","Août","Septembre","Octobre","Novembre","Décembre"];
  var days = ["po","wr","sr","cz","pl","so","nd"];
  var dateString = Browser.inputBox('Enter the month with format "mm-yyyy"');
  var date = new Date(dateString.split("-")[1],dateString.split("-")[0]-1,1);
  var dateFin = new Date(dateString.split("-")[1],dateString.split("-")[0]-1,0);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var pos =sheet.getLastColumn();
  sheet.insertColumnsAfter(pos,dateFin.getDate());
  var monthRange = sheet.getRange(1,parseInt(pos+1),1,parseInt(dateFin.getDate()));
  monthRange.merge();
  monthRange.setValue(month[dateDebut.getMonth()]);
  var daysOfMonth = [];
  for(var i=1;i<=dateFin.getDate();i++){
    daysOfMonth.push(days[date.getDay()+(i%7)-1]);
  }
  sheet.getRange(2,parseInt(pos+1),1,parseInt(dateFin.getDate())).setValues(daysOfMonth);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling the truth. Your variable `sheet` is of [Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet), which does not have a method `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)` - that is a method of [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#getRange%28Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer%29).

Change your assignment of variable `sheet` to ensure it's the right type:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

When you're writing your script, pay attention to the autocomplete feature, which would have helped to avoid this error. See [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18007676/1677912) for more details.

Comment: Thank you, 9 years later, this answer keeps on giving !!!