# Update Docs template from spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm able to create a copy of the template and rename it. But I can't get the data from my spreadsheet to populate the new Doc. Error message:

TypeError: Cannot find function getBody in object File.

I'm assuming that the copy function does not open the document, and I need to open it before I can access the body, but I don't know how to open the document since I'm creating it and don't know it's ID yet.

```
var file = DocsList.find("Primary Conducting Sheet TEMPLATE")[0];
var copy = file.makeCopy("Primary Conducting Sheet for Upcoming Sunday");
var body = copy.getBody();
body.replaceText('{date}', sheet.getRange('B2').getValues());
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005181/move-data-from-cells-in-worksheet-to-another-sheet-using-gas/18007676#18007676) about Class / Method matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a confusion between `DocsList` file object and `documentApp` Document object.

When you have your copy use `getId()` to get its ID and then open it with the `DocumentApp` method.

exemple with step by step :

```
var file = DocsList.find("Primary Conducting Sheet TEMPLATE")[0];
var copy = file.makeCopy("Primary Conducting Sheet for Upcoming Sunday");
var copyId = copy.getId();
var docCopy = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
var body = docCopy.getBody();
body.replaceText('{date}', sheet.getRange('B2').getValues());
```

**EDIT :** *and also, read the post that Mogsdad refers to in its comment, it will definitely help you to avoid this kind of errors ;-)*

Comment: Serge, I knew you'd answer the call. Works like a charm. Thanks for the explanation and the code.

Comment: You're welcome :-). Just a question:  why are you using getValues with an s to get a single cell value?

Comment: Because I have no background in coding and am teaching myself by searching these forums! Does it work just as well to do .getValue() without the 's'? Am I hurting anything by using with the 's' and only getting single cell? Thanks!

Comment: Good answer ! (no kidding) The thing is that getValues returns a matrix of values (in this case an array with only one value in it) instead of a single value and that might cause some troubles sometimes. Look eventually at the logger.log feature and the execution transcript, you'll see some [brackets] that indicates the "array type". I have a lot of sympathy for self learning people, keep going and good luck ;-)